# How to return else of an if statement outside the for loop the if statement is in

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a sequelize query that finds all users who have an attribute of can_upload = 1 which allows them to upload file to database. For that I loop through all the users who have attribute of can_upload = 1 and then I have an if statement which checks if the email of the user sent in request header matches any single on that was iterated in the for loop.

This part is fine, but I cannot return the else{} within this for loop since, if the email in the req header is not equal to the first value iterated then the loop will stop and the else{} statement will return without checking the other values in the loop.

```
users.findAll({where: {can_upload: 1}}).then(projectUsers=>{ 
var email = "";
 for (let i=0; i<projectUsers.length;i++){
   email=projectUsers[i].dataValues.email_address;
    if (email === req.headers.email_address) {
         //do a bunch of stuff
         res.status(200).send{`message: success`};
    }
 }
//somehow return the else here which would return 
res.status(401).send{`message: user is not authorized to upload`};
)};
```

Comment: Can't you just save a status indicating whether or not it was found and use it after the loop? And if you're checking against an email can't you just also search for that email?

Comment: It seems easier to do a request on the email and then check the privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just include the email in the query to the database instead of returning ALL the users with can_upload = 1,

```
users.findAll({where: {
    can_upload: 1, email_address: req.headers.email_address} }).then(projectUsers=>{ /* logic */ })
```

And now just check if projectUsers has a length > 0

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
users.findAll({where: {
    can_upload: 1, 'dataValues.email_address': req.headers.email_address}
}).then(projectUsers=>{ // do whatever you need here // }
```